# pandas style.applymap not working for large datasets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working in Jupyter Notebook 6.1.4 with Pandas 1.1.3 on Windows 10.

I have a dataframe with 2000 rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

c = np.random.choice

colours = ['blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'green... no, blue']
knights = ['Bedevere', 'Galahad', 'Arthur', 'Robin', 'Lancelot']
qualities = ['wise', 'brave', 'pure', 'not quite so brave']

dfsize = 2000

knights = pd.DataFrame({'name_id':c(range(dfsize), dfsize, replace=False),
              'favourite_colour':c(colours, dfsize),
              'favourite_knight':c(knights, dfsize),
              'favourite_quality':c(qualities, dfsize)})
```

I create a copy, and a dataframe comparing the two (obviously this will just be a dataframe full of True values).

```
knights2 = knights.copy()

same = knights.eq(knights2)
```

I create a function to feed to a pandas Styler object to highlight the dataframe

```
def highlight_true(value):
    if value == True:
        return "background-color:green"
    else:
        return "background-color:red"
```

I display the new highlighted dataframe

```
display(same.style.applymap(highlight_true))
```

All cells are highlighted green as expected.

But if I increase the size of the dataframe to say 3000

```
dfsize = 3000
```

It highlights up to row 2049 and then leaves the rest unhighlighted (neither green nor red). Can anyone explain what is happening here? Does applymap have a limit to how large a dataframe it will highlight? Does this happen on all computers / versions of Jupyter Notebook/ Pandas or just the ones I'm working with? Is there a way to fix this so pandas can highlight large dataframes? Is anyone able to reproduce this result? What size dataframes did you test it on? What version of Pandas/ Jupyter Notebook did you use? Thank you.

EDIT: Additional info I've just found in case it helps anyone figure out what's going wrong: If I create another copy with some different values and compare this to the original:

```
some_rows = [0, 1000, 2000, 2500, 3000]
dfsize = 3500

knights3 = knights.copy()

for x in some_rows:
    knights3.loc[x, 'favourite_quality'] = "a different value"

same2 = knights.eq(knights3)
display(same2.style.applymap(highlight_true))
```

It stops highlighting True values in green at row 2049 as before, but carries on through the dataframe just highlighting the False values in red (and leaving the True values unhighlighted).

Comment: can't reproduce this on my system. All are highlighted correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask what system are you using and what size dataframes did you try?